# How to replace a complicated C-style for loop in Swift 2.2

Tags: swift

For an unsigned integer type library that I've developed, I have a specialized C-style for loop used for calculating the significant bits in a stored numeric value. I have been struggling for some time with how to convert this into a Swift 2.2+ style for loop. Here's the code in question:

```
/// Counts up the significant bits in stored data.
public var significantBits: UInt128 {
    // Will turn into final result.
    var significantBitCount: UInt128 = 0
    // The bits to crawl in loop.
    var bitsToWalk: UInt64 = 0
    if self.value.upperBits > 0 {
        bitsToWalk = self.value.upperBits
        // When upperBits > 0, lowerBits are all significant.
        significantBitCount += 64
    } else if self.value.lowerBits > 0 {
        bitsToWalk = self.value.lowerBits
    }
    if bitsToWalk > 0 {
        // Walk significant bits by shifting right until all bits are equal to 0.
        for var bitsLeft = bitsToWalk; bitsLeft > 0; bitsLeft >>= 1 {
            significantBitCount += 1
        }
    }
    return significantBitCount
}
```

I'm sure there are multiple ways to handle this, and I can think of some more verbose means of handling this, but I'm interested in finding a succinct way of handling this scenario that I can reapply to similar circumstances. I find that I very rarely use C-style for loops, but when I do, it's for bizarre scenarios like this one where it's the most succinct way to handle a problem.

Comment: Can't you replace this with "while" loop?

Comment: You could simply use a `while` loop, or [this cool code](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/124572/36366) from [@MartinR](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r).

Comment: @nhgrif you can see the entirety of my source on GitHub by loading up my  UInt128 project.

Comment: You didn't link to it.  But actually, what would be perfectly ideal is if you just boiled your question down to the actual relevant portion (just the loop) and contained the exact minimum amount of code around it for it to work if I copy & paste it into a playground.  Plus some tests cases.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use `log2()` to calculate the number of significant bits?

Comment: @nhgrif, I appreciate your input and understand where you're coming from. I actually thought quite a bit about how much code to include. My purpose for this question was to trigger some debate about some of the more complicated situations involving C-style for loops in Swift. IMO the code I have provided gives just the right amount of context for an intelligent conversation, without becoming a wall of text for my entire code base.

Comment: I actually think you could (and should) have posted significantly less.  This question is only about the `for` loop.  It took me a little bit of work to figure out exactly what context was necessary--I want to make sure my answer provides the same result.  You could have simply posted something [about like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/q3quP.png).  It cuts the code down to exactly what you're actually asking about and even better, includes some test cases which could have prevented @Sulthan's original incorrect answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution is to just use a `while` loop:

Replace this code:

> ```
> if bitsToWalk > 0 {
>     // Walk significant bits by shifting right until all bits are equal to 0.
>     for var bitsLeft = bitsToWalk; bitsLeft > 0; bitsLeft >>= 1 {
>         significantBitCount += 1
>     }
> }
> ```

With the following `while` loop:

```
while bitsToWalk > 0 {
    significantBitCount += 1
    bitsToWalk >>= 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was my thought as well. And in my case was probably the best answer before the Swift changes. From all of my research, it looks like Swift no longer includes syntax that supports more complicated steppings now that C-style for loops are being deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the built-in processor functions:

Put:

```
#import <x86intrin.h>
```

to your Obj-C bridging header and then in Swift:

```
let number: UInt64 = 111
let mostSignificantBit = _lzcnt_u64(number)

print(mostSignificantBit)
```

(Of course, you have to be on the correct architecture, this function is defined only on x86. This solution is not exactly well portable).

Comment: Is this the OS X or iOS solution?

Comment: The original code isn't counting the number of set bits, though. It's finding the highest set bit. Maybe you meant `_lzcnt_u64`?

Comment: Explain how? If I set `bitsToWalk` to 2, `significantBitCount` is 2. If I set `bitsToWalk` to 3, `significantBitCount` is also 2.

Answer (score 1):

This function should calculate the number of significant bits in a `UInt64` value:

```
import Foundation

func significantBits(n: UInt64) -> Int {
    return Int(ceil(log2(Double(n))))
}

let n: UInt64 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  //  64 significant bits
let m: UInt64 = 0b11011             //  5 significant bits

print("n has \(significantBits(n)) significant bits.")
print("m has \(significantBits(m)) significant bits.")
```

and outputs:

```
n has 64 significant bits.
m has 5 significant bits.
```

You could probably replace your code with something like:

```
private func calcSigBits(n: UInt64) -> Int {
    return Int(ceil(log2(Double(n))))
}

public var significantBits: Int {
    if self.value.upperBits > 0 {
        return calcSigBits(self.value.upperBits) + 64
    }
    else {
        return calcSigBits(self.value.lowerBits)
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use `log2`, you can use the loop from nhgrif's answer, but it's still good to refactor this out, since it's a conceptually separate operation, and makes your own code much simpler. You could even add it as an extension to `UInt64`:

```
extension UInt64 {
    public var significantBits: Int {
        var sb = 0
        var value = self
        while value > 0 {
            sb += 1
            value >>= 1
        }
        return sb
    }
}

//  Rest of your class definition...

public var significantBits: Int {
    if self.value.upperBits > 0 {
        return self.value.upperBits.significantBits + 64
    }
    else {
        return self.value.lowerBits.significantBits
    }
}
```